# Combine elements from list of lists by picking the first element from one and 2nd through n from the next

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am new to python and I am trying to find a way to do the following:

I have a list that comprises of 2 lists within - (this could be any number)
**master = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]**

Each of the items contain the same number of values (in this case 4 values per list item in the master list).

I want to get the following output -

```
sublst =
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], #1 all elements from 1st item

     [1, 2, 3, 8], #2 first 3 elements from 1st item and the last element from the second

     [1, 2, 7, 8], #3 first 2 elements from 1st item and last two elements from the second

     [1, 6, 7, 8], #4 first element from 1st item and 2 thru 4 elements from the second

     [5, 6, 7, 8], #5 all elements from 2nd item

     [5, 6, 7, 4], #6 first 3 elements from 2nd item and the last element from the first

     [5, 6, 3, 4], #7 first 2 elements from 2nd item and last two elements from the first

     [5, 2, 3, 4]] #8 first element from 2nd item and 2 thru 4 elements from the first
```

The above should be repeated for all list items within the master list (in this case I only have 2 lists within the master, but it could be more).

I know how to get the first element of every item in the master list, but i dont know how to get the first element from 1st item and 2 thru end from 2nd item and so on.

I am using Python 3.8.3.

Your help is much appreciated.

--Update 7/9/2020--
As requested by one of the users, I am adding some sample test cases -

1. master = [ [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16] ].
   sublist = [ [1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,3,12],[1,2,3,16],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,7,12],[1,2,7,16],[1,2,11,8],[1,2,11,12],[1,2,11,16],[1,2,15,8],[1,2,15,12],[1,2,15,16],[1,6,7,8],[1,6,7,12],[1,6,7,16],[1,6,11,8],[1,6,11,12],[1,6,11,16],[1,6,15,8],[1,6,15,12],[1,6,15,16],[1,10,7,8],[1,10,7,12],[1,10,7,16],[1,10,11,8],[1,10,11,12],[1,10,11,16],[1,10,15,8],[1,10,15,12],[1,10,15,16],[1,14,7,8],[1,14,7,12],[1,14,7,16],[1,14,11,8],[1,14,11,12],[1,14,11,16],[1,14,15,8],[1,14,15,12],[1,14,15,16],    [5,6,7,8],[5,6,7,4]......]
   Note: There are 40 combinations with [1,2,3,4] as the base set. If we use [5,6,7,8] as the base, we will have another 40 combinations and so on. For the above, there will be a total of 40 *4 = 160 combinations possible.

I dont really need the combinations, just their sum. However, we first need to identify each combination so we can get the sum of each.
final = [10,14,18,22,18,22,26,22,26,30,26,30,34,......]

Order does not matter, duplicates are fine.
I have the numbers in the master set to be unique so as to avoid confusion.

2. master = [ [0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8] ].
   sublist = [ [0,1,2],[0,1,5],[0,1,8],[0,4,5],[0,4,8],[0,7,5],[0,7,8],[3,4,5],[3,4,2],[3,4,8],[3,1,2],[3,1,8],[3,7,2],[3,7,8],[6,7,8],[6,7,2],[6,7,5],[6,1,2],[6,1,5],[6,4,2],[6,4,5] ]
   final = [3,6,9,9,12,12,15,12,9,15,6,12,12,18,21,15,18,9,12,12,15]

With base set as [0,1,2], we will have 7 combinations, so total number of values in the final list is 7 * 3 = 21.

The code from Eduardo is working, but for larger lists, it is taking a very long time to process probably because his solution is creating that massive list with all possible combinations. If we were to identify each combination and store just the sum, then I think his solution will be faster. I am still trying to modify that solution.

I was initially trying to get this implemented using n-ary trees in C, but thought Python might have a better way if I could get the permutations going.

Hope this helps!

PS: This is my first post on stackoverflow, so if there is any information that is missing, I apologize. I have tried to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: Is the order of lists in your final list important?

Comment: No, the order is not important. In fact, I only need the sum of the elements from each of those sublists, for eg: [2,2,2,2] = 8 is what I would need.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
def get_part_answer(l1, l2):
    n = len(l1)
    return [l1[:i] + l2[i:] for i in range(len(l1), 0, -1)]

def get_answer(l):
    list1, list2 = l
    return get_part_answer(list1, list2) + get_part_answer(list2, list1)

master = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
print(get_answer(master))
```

which gives:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 2, 7, 8], [1, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 4], [5, 6, 3, 4], [5, 2, 3, 4]]
```

What is happening here is that you can slice a list using `[:i]` to mean the first i elements, and `[i:]` to mean the remaining elements after the first i elements - concatenate each of these, and put it in decreasing loop over `i` from length of list down to 1 -- that is half the answer, then do the same for the two lists in the other order.

It does not check that the lists are the same size. You could add a check and raise `ValueError` if they are not.

Comment: Appreciate your response, however, my challenge is there could be N lists part of the master.For Eg:[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]....].Your code will work when master contains two lists.I am trying with zip to get all the combinations, but I am unable to get it to work.The code has to run through the iterator to pick index 'x' (0 to N) from one list and x+1:end from other lists. In the above case, I should have [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,3,12],[1,2,3,16],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,11,12],[1,2,15,16],[1,2,7,12],[1,2,7,16],[1,2,11,8],[1,2,11,16],[1,2,15,8],[1,2,15,12]...].Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools permutations to get all combinations of your list elements (since order does not matter for OP, it works for any number of lists):

```
from itertools import permutations
sublst = master+[l1[:i]+l2[i:] for (l1,l2) in permutations(master,2) for i in range(len(master[0])-1,0,-1)]
```

output for `master = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 2, 7, 8], [1, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 4], [5, 6, 3, 4], [5, 2, 3, 4]]
```

output for `master = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]`:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 2, 7, 8], [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 12], [1, 2, 11, 12], [1, 10, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 4], [5, 6, 3, 4], [5, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 12], [5, 6, 11, 12], [5, 10, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 4], [9, 10, 3, 4], [9, 2, 3, 4], [9, 10, 11, 8], [9, 10, 7, 8], [9, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: appreciate this Ehsan, however, your code is missing the following combinations - [1,2,7,12],[1,6,7,12], etc - basically the permutation where we select one or two values from index 0 and the next from index 1 and the next from index 2. This is giving me an incorrect result on one my larger sets which has 10 lists of each containing 9 values. Eg: [1,2,1,1,3,2,4,1,2], [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2]....upto 10 such lists within the master list.

Comment: @user2234132 You keep changing the question. That is not what I understood from your question or comment on the post below. Could you please provide us with a 3 list (of maybe each of length 3) example input and output to understand better? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ehsan, I dont think I changed my question, I gave a simple case there but also mentioned that there could be more elements. Let me give you a couple of examples -

Comment: @user2234132 Maybe it was not clear to me. A 3 element input/output will help us understand better. Thank you

Comment: Added more test cases to the question. Hope that clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
def subpart(master):
    def subpart_(current, inListIndex, inMasterIndex, master, sublists):
        if inListIndex != 0:
            for lst in master:
                if lst != master[inMasterIndex]:
                    current[inListIndex] = lst[inListIndex]
                    if current not in sublists: sublists.append(list(current))
                    sublists = subpart_(list(current), inListIndex-1, inMasterIndex, master, sublists)
        
        return sublists
    
    sublist = []
    for i in range(len(master)):
        mylist = list(master[i])
        sublist.append(list(mylist))
        sublist = subpart_(mylist, len(mylist)-1, i, master, sublist)

    return sublist
```

It outputs the combination of all the elements with different indexes in the lists of master. However not sure if in the pretended order and its not very efficient, sorry about that.

It uses recursion to interchange each new iteration with the elements of the other lists.
For:

```
master = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

It outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 2, 7, 8], [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 10, 7, 8], [1, 2, 11, 8], [1, 6, 11, 8], [1, 10, 11, 8], [1, 6, 3, 8], [1, 10, 3, 8], [1, 2, 3, 12], [1, 2, 7, 12], [1, 6, 7, 12], [1, 10, 7, 12], [1, 2, 11, 12], [1, 6, 11, 12], [1, 10, 11, 12], [1, 6, 3, 12], [1, 10, 3, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 4], [5, 6, 3, 4], [5, 2, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 6, 11, 4], [5, 2, 11, 4], [5, 10, 11, 4], [5, 2, 7, 4], [5, 10, 7, 4], [5, 6, 7, 12], [5, 6, 3, 12], [5, 2, 3, 12], [5, 10, 3, 12], [5, 6, 11, 12], [5, 2, 11, 12], [5, 10, 11, 12], [5, 2, 7, 12], [5, 10, 7, 12], [9, 10, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 4], [9, 10, 3, 4], [9, 2, 3, 4], [9, 6, 3, 4], [9, 10, 7, 4], [9, 2, 7, 4], [9, 6, 7, 4], [9, 2, 11, 4], [9, 6, 11, 4], [9, 10, 11, 8], [9, 10, 3, 8], [9, 2, 3, 8], [9, 6, 3, 8], [9, 10, 7, 8], [9, 2, 7, 8], [9, 6, 7, 8], [9, 2, 11, 8], [9, 6, 11, 8]]
```

Hopefully I was of any help.

Comment: Thanks, this works for smaller lists, but when the sublists grow, this takes a very long time to finish. I only need the totals for each combination, so I am trying to modify your code to return a list with just the totals for each combination. Hopefully that reduces memory usage and speeds up processing.

Comment: @user2234132 Thank you and sorry for the bad efficiency. If I manage to improve it I'll edit my answer. If you also reach a more optimized version could you please also post it, as I'm becoming rather curious to see the end result. Thanks.

Comment: absolutely, I will ensure the final solution is posted here. Thanks again, yours is a good start for me because I am able to get something working.